# Problem with vertical spacing in table

Tags: tables

### Objective

I want to create a simple n x 1 table with a thick colored border on the left side.

### My approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,arydshln,xcolor,colortbl}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}


\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{blue!70}\VRule[4pt]}m{4cm}}
{ABC}\\
{DEF}\\
{GHI}\\
{JKL}\\
{MNO}\\
{PQRS}\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Result1:

[image: Example 1]

Result2 (using NiceMatrix):

[image: Example 2]

### Problem

Since I am using latex because I like the correct and clean look, some minor things dont please me.

- The border shows "visual" separations of the rows. This is an effect of \Large. I can get rid of this using nicematrix package. However this is just a workaround in my opinion. Moreover, the border is extended even more (see result2)
- The Cells are not centered vertically in their cells in my opinion.(See Image1) In my opinion, there is more space between table bottom to the lower cell content and the table top to the top of the upper cell content.

I already did some research but none of the solutions in the internet solved my problem. Using NiceTabular gets rid of problem #1, but the spacing problem still remains.

Comment: If you want to avoid the thin white lines (which are shown in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom), you should use `nicematrix`.

Comment: Please tell us which pdf viewer you employ. Please also clarify what you mean by "The cells are not centered vertically in their cells". (As it stands, the expression sounds a bit self-contradictory.)

Comment: Currently I use the TexMaker internal PDF Reader, foxit PDF reader and the Apple PDF Preview tool. Problems exists in all of these three. I also added another example where the spacing problem becomes clearer I think

Answer (score 2):

Two examples: left a wee bit modified your code, right with use of the `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\arrayrulecolor{blue!70}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{| l<{\vphantom{Q}}}
    ABC     \\
    DEF     \\
    GHI     \\
    JKL     \\
    MNO     \\
    PQRS    
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l<{\vphantom{Q}}}
    ABC     \\
    DEF     \\
    GHI     \\
    JKL     \\
    MNO     \\
    PQRS    
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the blue line is at `NiceTabular` longer, we should ask author of package: @F. Pantigny ...

Comment: Thank you! Via this approach I can get rid of the discontinuous border line!

Comment: @F. Pantigny, why  vertical lines at `NiceTabular` longer as at standar `tabular` table?

Comment: @Zarko: In fact, the rules drawn by `NiceTabular` are drawn with PGF/Tikz and the vertical rules are longer than the rules of `array` by a quantity equal to `\arrayrulewidth` in order to have a perfect join with the potential horizontal rules. However, maybe I will add a key to control that point in a future version of `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the intended se case, a simple `tabular` inside of a `tcolorbox` could be an alternative apporach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced,
    hbox,
    boxrule=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{blue!70},
    colback=white,
    sharp corners, 
    boxsep=0pt
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
ABC\\
DEF\\
GHI\\
JKL\\
MNO\\
PQRS\\
\end{tabular}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```